# Spring MVC - GSON seraializing nulls

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

GSON ommits `null` fields while serailizing. While using Spring MVC in Java, is there any annotation that can be used to include `null` fields while serializing using GSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if annotaion to serialize null object in GSON exists. But you can use `.serializeNulls()` to include null fields.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

Comment: Worked perfect. There is no need of annotations. serializeNulls() is the solution.